# Dissolve multiple overlapping polygons into one polygon covering the extent for all such instances of overlapping polygons

Tags: qgis, arcmap, polygon, overlapping-features, dissolve

I have a polygon layer in which some polygons are close to one another whereas some polygons are just alone and do not have other polygons in vicinity. So I created a 10 meter buffer, I want to keep all the overlapping polygons and get rid of the non-overlapping polygons.

I have tried using the dissolve tool, but I do not have any common attribute value between the overlapping polygons. So it is merging all the polygons into 1 feature. I am using QGIS version 3.16.

How can I do this using basic licensing of QGIS?

[image]

I have more such cases, I do not need a full 1 big polygon for all the intersecting spots, I need separate features for intersecting polygons. The problem with dissolve is that it makes feature count as 1.

[image]

Comment: In QGIS if you click ["Show advanced parameter"](https://pasteboard.co/YdPWJyr7oYhO.png) you have the option "Keep disjoint features separate" . Does that solve your problem? You only have this option when using the Dissolve tool in the Vector geometry tool group, there is also a dissolve in the GDAL group.

Comment: Please decide whether it is QGIS or ArcMap that you wish to ask about in this particular question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it by selecting overlaping polygons, save them as new shapefile and then dissolve it to obtain 1 big polygon. So first to choose overlaping polygons use Vector > Research Tools > Select by Location and select the overlap and croos options.
[image]

Then export selected features as geopackage or esri shapefile.

[image]

This file contains only overlaping polygons, then you should use GDAL > Vector geoprocessing > Dissolve from processing toolbox.

[image]

and select the option "Produce one feature for each geometry....."

[image]

Comment: But by doing that all such cases will be counted as 1, I dont want that there are many such cases and I want the clustered polygons to get merged and stay 1 unit, similaryly beside that there are several other such clustered cases which will be counted as 1, total count = 2

Comment: Ah I understand that, I just edited the answer, can you try it, this worked for me.

Comment: hey thanks, the saga tool worked

Comment: Can you please suggest some similar tools in arcmap?